# Docker container cannot connect to the Internet, ping works, wget fails

Tags: linux, docker, debian, docker-network

I am trying to find a solution for days now and ended up asking questions here...

I have Debian 10 with Docker installed, a container connects to the other containers without any problem, but I cannot figure out what needs to be done to access the Internet from the containers.

1. A container can do a ping and gets the replies:

```
docker run -i -t busybox ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: seq=0 ttl=53 time=10.156 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: seq=1 ttl=53 time=10.516 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: seq=2 ttl=53 time=10.218 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: seq=3 ttl=53 time=10.487 ms
```

2. Unfortunately, when I try to use wget it fails:

```
docker run -i -t busybox wget -S -T 5 http://google.com
Connecting to google.com (216.58.209.14:80)
wget: download timed out
```

3. The containers DNS seem to be properly set up:

```
docker run -i -t busybox cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

4. OS details and docker version:

```
uname -a
Linux host1 4.19.0-8-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.98-1 (2020-01-26) x86_64 GNU/Linux

docker -v
Docker version 19.03.8, build afacb8b7f0
```

5. Docker bridge network details:

```
docker network inspect bridge
[
    {
        "Name": "bridge",
        "Id": "970f8f04c009361b831d8ff8b4fa6d223645aadbbe93a27576d4934c0a8710e0",
        "Created": "2020-04-23T17:15:37.376767708+02:00",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.17.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {},
        "Options": {
            "com.docker.network.bridge.default_bridge": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4": "0.0.0.0",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.name": "docker0",
            "com.docker.network.driver.mtu": "1500"
        },
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

6. iptables are enabled and configured, however I have also tried with clear rules (ACCEPT all), still no luck:

```
iptables -nvL
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 484 packets, 40785 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    2   116 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443 state NEW
 2501  309K ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    3   192 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:1337
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    8   498 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:1194 state NEW
   10   640 ACCEPT     all  --  tun0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   70  4889 DOCKER-USER  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
   46  3449 DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
   14  1164 ACCEPT     all  --  *      docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 DOCKER     all  --  *      docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
   24  1607 ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 !docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    8   678 ACCEPT     all  --  tun0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  tun0   ens192  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  ens192 tun+    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 10 packets, 733 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 1782 1233K ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      lo      0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      tun0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain DOCKER (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   24  1607 DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  docker0 !docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
   46  3449 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   24  1440 REJECT     tcp  --  ens192 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
   46  3449 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
   24  1607 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

```
iptables -t nat -nvL
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 516 packets, 43250 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  290 14045 DOCKER     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 18 packets, 1101 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 10 packets, 744 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   10   590 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      !docker0  172.17.0.0/16        0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 MASQUERADE  tcp  --  *      *       172.17.0.2           172.17.0.2           tcp dpt:80

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 9 packets, 666 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 DOCKER     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0           !127.0.0.0/8          ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain DOCKER (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  docker0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

Any idea why my containers cannot connect to the outside world?

EDIT:

I have tried cleaning up completely my iptables rules and allow all traffic:

```
iptables -nvL

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 12968 packets, 945K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 83 packets, 7850 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination



iptables -t nat -nvL

Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 12871 packets, 939K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 37 packets, 1856 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 29 packets, 2447 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 29 packets, 2447 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         



iptables -t mangle -nvL

Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

In such case even pings are not going out of the container:

```
docker run -i -t busybox ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8): 56 data bytes
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
7 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss
```